# What is the best way to save the model when the input is json?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have below json as input from the client

```
[
{'id': 0, 'name': 'Housing', 'value': 3}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Bank', 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Entertainment', 'value': 3}
]
```

It is being assigned to inputV_wc object in my view like below

**View:**

```
def savemore(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data=json.loads(request.body.decode())
        inputV_wc = data['wc']
    else:
        response_data = 'You have not saved any data!'
        return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
    try:
        if not inputV_wc:
            test=''
        else:
            # WC - Insert wc again on each save rather update - time consuming
            if js_wex.objects.filter(pid = request.session.get('pid')).exists():
                js_wex.objects.filter(pid=request.session.get('pid')).delete()
            wc = js_wex(pid=request.session.get('pid'), wcname=inputV_wc[0]['name'],rating=inputV_wc[0]['value'],ordernum=inputV_wc[0]['id'])
            wc.save()
            wc = js_wex(pid=request.session.get('pid'), wcname=inputV_wc[1]['name'],rating=inputV_wc[1]['value'],ordernum=inputV_wc[1]['id'])
            wc.save()
            wc = js_wex(pid=request.session.get('pid'), wcname=inputV_wc[2]['name'],rating=inputV_wc[2]['value'],ordernum=inputV_wc[2]['id'])
            wc.save()
    except Exception as e:
        response_data = 'Ouch! Something went wrong!'+str(e)
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
```

Currently if my input json has 5 rows, certainly the above view fails with Index out of range.. 
and if input json has 2 rows it again fails with missing entry - model cannot be saved.

How can I write my view such that if json has varied number of objects like

input from one user -

```
[
{'id': 0, 'name': 'Housing', 'value': 14}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Bank', 'value': 18} 
]
```

input from other user -

```
[
{'id': 0, 'name': 'Housing', 'value': 3}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Bank', 'value': 18}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Housing1', 'value': 14}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Bank1', 'value': 12} 
]
```

can be handled ?

Json rows could be from 1 to 15 maximum for each input.

I read about using **kwargs, for handling similar scenario.. but I couldn't figure out how to apply for saving my model for varied json input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you just want to use a [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
for row in inputV_wc:
    wc = js_wex(pid=request.session.get('pid'), wcname=row['name'], rating=row['value'], ordernum=row['id'])
    wc.save()
```

If you want to insert all the objects at once, based on what you have shown you could probably use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create):

```
rows = []
for row in inputV_wc:
    wc = js_wex(pid=request.session.get('pid'), wcname=row['name'], rating=row['value'], ordernum=row['id'])
    rows.append(wc)

js_wex.objects.bulk_create(rows)
```

Comment: Is Justin, with the for loop or with manual version, we have to traverse to DB multiple times for each row.. Is there any better way to accomplish this in one go ? (to the DB)

Comment: Great question. You could probably use `bulk_create`. See my update above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin! I will try this